# starting pry shell on linux

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, pry

When i enter the `pry` command to start the pry shell i get this :

[Output here.Unable to post on SO](http://i46.tinypic.com/2pt3prc.png)

Why doesn't the pry shell start up ?

Installation commands were :

```
rvm pkg install zlib
gem install pry pry-doc
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: What about `irb` is it working correctly?

Comment: It looks like you need to install the readline library. What OS are you using?

Comment: Try this http://biztech.sheprador.com/?p=81

Comment: @mrzasa [In not the same manner!](http://i49.tinypic.com/oidppf.png)

Comment: @Mark Thomas [i get this when i run the `irb` shell](http://i49.tinypic.com/oidppf.png)

Comment: As Mark Thomas said, you need to install readline. If you use RVM, [their howto](https://rvm.io//packages/readline/) might be helpful.